# What data type is 16 bits in 32-bit OS and 32bits in 64-bit OS?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 32bit-64bit

I'm looking for a datatype (which will be used as an Index), it should be 16 bits in 32-bit os and 32-bits in 64-bit OS. I use VS2010, and I'm aware that HALF_PTR can be used but it doesn't sound good when used for index and I can still typedef it to a more meaningful name, but before that is there any defined datatype that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: C and C++ don't make any promises in that regard, so you'll have to read your compiler's documentation.

Comment: These kind of questions suck when they don't explain why such a weird animal is needed.  With extra hackles up when the SO user name starts with "Novice".  Using a *short* to index an array in 32-bit code is **not** an optimization.  Far from it.

Comment: @Hans Passant, it is used to write a field in a binary blob header. This particular field should be 16-bits in a 32-bit OS and 32-bits in 64-bits OS. It is not used as array index for space optimization.

Comment: The only thing that matters is what kind of process is going to *read* it.  Which is not necessarily a 64-bit process on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: @HansPassant, Application does not have LARGEADDRESSAWARE enabled. Its a in-memory binary blob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use traits to make a type alias that suits your system:

```
#include <cstdint>

template <unsigned int> struct HalfPtrImpl;
template <> struct HalfPtrImpl<4> { typedef uint16_t type; };
template <> struct HalfPtrImpl<8> { typedef uint32_t type; };

typedef HalfPtrImpl<sizeof(uintptr_t)>::type HalfPtr;
```

Now use `HalfPtr` as your type.

(You can shortcut the above by using `std::conditional` a couple of times. Many ways to skin this cat.)

Comment: 32 **byte** integers?  That's one very wide datapath!

Comment: @BenVoigt: Who what where? :-)